# Is resonance always stabilizing

Tags: resonance

Does resonance always stabilize a molecule or can resonance effects destabilize molecules?

The only example I can think of in which resonance (more accurately, conjugation) destabilizes molecules is in the cases of anti-aromatic compounds. Is this a valid example, and are there any more such examples?

Comment: If resonance is not stabilizing, then why would it occur?

Comment: Couldn't you say that about a lot of things? If anti-aromatic compounds were unstable, why do they exist? I think the answer to your question lies with meta-stability.

Comment: What I was trying to point out is stated by Ron, `Resonance only occurs when the result is beneficial`. Anti-aromatic compounds exist since the molecular bonding releases energy from the state of individual atoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resonance only occurs when the result is beneficial, that is when a more-stabilized molecule will result. If resonance (delocalization) occurred in a compound such as cyclobutadiene to produce a square molecule with equivalent bond lengths, an antiaromatic molecule would be the result.  Therefore, resonance does not occur and a square molecule with equivalent bond lengths is not produced.

Comment: As you say that a square molecule with equivalent bond length will not result therefore the rectangular molecule will be called anti aromatic or non aromatic?

Comment: The double bonds will be localized, the molecule will be non-aromatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, resonance can definitely destabilize.

One example you can think of is **destabilization of carbanions**, which is something we often consider when trying to determine the relative acidities of some given species.

Consider the relative acidities of **o-Methoxytoluene**, **m-Methoxytoluene** and **p-Methoxytoluene**. Destabilization of their respective conjugate bases due to resonance plays an important role here, as mentioned in the renowned book **Solomons|Frhyle|Snyder**.

[image: solomon]

As clear in the attached figure, **+R effect**, where a substituent increases the electron density in a ring, destabilizes the conjugate base. Hence, the order of relative acidities here is: **B > A > C**

I encourage the reader to try and draw the resonance canonical forms for the three species mentioned, and realize why this happens for themselves.